# Convert 3 Successive bytes to two int

Tags: c#, bit-shift, endianness

I am familiar in converting two successive bytes into on int 1:

The format I want is in Little Endian

```
int number= ((int)BYTE2<<8) | ((int)BYTE1);
```

Now I set up the camera to send me the data in 12packed format. This means that to get one byte I need to have the first byte whole and I need only 4 bits from the second byte.

As a result every 3 bytes I can have two 12bit int numbers:

I need to get the first Byte whole and the first 4 bits form the second Byte and combine these 12 bits into an int with little endian format.

Then I need to take the last 4bits from the seond Byte and the whole third Byte and combine them in little endian order to get the second int. See the attached picture.

[image]

How can I use the bit shift operations to achieve this?

Sorry but I am not familiar with bit shifting operations

I doubt this is the correct way but is this at least the correct approach?

```
int FirstInt= ((int)(BYTE2 & 0xF0)<<8) | ((int)BYTE1);
int SecondInt= ((int)BYTE3<<8) | ((int)(BYTE2 & 0x0F));
```

Comment: Yes, looks about right to me if the bottom of byte2 are the least-significant bits of the second int - except you'd want to shift byte3 left by 4 not 8.

Comment: Thank you for your anser Uwe Keim. So you think I shall have it like this: int SecondInt= ((int)BYTE3<<4) | ((int)(BYTE2 & 0x0F));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all data bytes you can use a a BitArray.

```
byte[] completeData = //your data
```

I have two functions that are used to transform it to big endian, you can convert it to little endian.

```
     public static BitArray ToBigEndian(byte[] byteArray)
     {
        if (byteArray == null)
        {
           return null;
        }
        BitArray bitArray;

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
           bitArray = new BitArray(byteArray.Length * 8);
           int offset = 0;
           foreach (var byteValue in byteArray)
           {
              for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
              {
                 bool isBitSet = (byteValue & (0x80 >> index)) > 0;
                 bitArray.Set(offset + index, isBitSet);
              }
              offset += 8;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           bitArray = new BitArray(byteArray);
        }
        return bitArray;
     }

     public static byte[] FromBigEndian(BitArray bitArray)
     {
        if (bitArray == null || bitArray.Length <= 0 || bitArray.Length % 8 > 0)
        {
           return null;
        }

        int countOfBytes = bitArray.Length / 8;

        byte[] byteArray = new byte[countOfBytes];


        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
           for (int index = 0; index < bitArray.Length; index += 8)
           {
              byte value = 0;
              int dataIndex = index / 8;
              for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
              {
                 bool isBitSet = bitArray[index + i];
                 value |= (byte)(((isBitSet ? 0x01 : 0) << (7 - i)));
              }
              byteArray[dataIndex] = value;
           }
        }
        else
        {
           bitArray.CopyTo(byteArray, 0);
        }
        return byteArray;
     }
```

This way you can loop your Bits:

```
BitArray completeBitArray = ToBigEndian(completeData);
```